# PHP while loop displays same result over and over again

Tags: php, loops, mysqli, while-loop

I'm using a while loop in order to display items from the database but this instead is displaying the same result and ignoring one.
Example: if the first items is called Item1 and I have 4 items in the database (Item1, Item2, Item3, Item4) it will display 3 times the Item1.

```
<?php
    $card_data =  mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM builds");
    $card_data_result = mysqli_fetch_array($card_data);
    $build_name = $card_data_result['build_name']; 

while ($card_data_result = mysqli_fetch_array($card_data)){
    echo "$build_name";
    }
?>
```

Any ideas how to fix it?

Comment: because you don't change the `$buildname` variable in the while loop.

Comment: You’re printing `$build_name`, which gets assigned outside the `while` loop. Try printing `$card_data_result['build_name']` instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this :

```
    $card_data =  mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM builds");
    //$card_data_result = mysqli_fetch_array($card_data);
    //$build_name = $card_data_result['build_name']; 
    while ($card_data_result = mysqli_fetch_array($card_data)){
        echo $card_data_result['build_name']."<br />";
    }
```

Explanation:
Following code only returns one row. To get more rows, you need a loop:

```
$card_data_result = mysqli_fetch_array($card_data);
$build_name = $card_data_result['build_name'];
```

Since you have 4 items, your `while` loop will print 4 times  `$build_name` (the same item)

Comment: whell, that works but the way i'm doing it i'm geting this error:  Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE, expecting T_STRING or T_VARIABLE or T_NUM_STRING in C:\wamp\www\pcbuilds\index.php on line 123 and line 123 is: <h2 class=\"card-title\">$card_data_result['build_name']</h2>

Comment: PHP and html concatenation seem incorrect..   echo "<h2 class=\"card-title\">".$card_data_result['build_name']."</h2>";

Comment: that works but again is not displaying one item from the list :/

Comment: Can you check running this query "SELECT * FROM builds" in your DB directly ? Does it return 4 items ?

Comment: Showing rows 0 - 2 ( ~3 total , Query took 0.0006 sec) (i removed one so now are 3 total)

Comment: So, what's you while loop result now ? Should display 3 items.

Comment: no, only 2 items. it wont display the first so i'm gonna make the first result called "null" i will leave there im not gonna touch it again :)

Answer (score 1):

Rewrite your **`while`** like this

```
while ($card_data_result = mysqli_fetch_array($card_data)){
echo $card_data_result['build_name']; //<---- Brought this statment inside what you had outside of the while loop
}
```

Comment: this will give me an error Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE, expecting T_STRING or T_VARIABLE or T_NUM_STRING in C:\wamp\www\pcbuilds\index.php on line 123 and line 123 is: <h2 class=\"card-title\">$card_data_result['build_name']</h2> which is inside <?php echo "" ?>